# How do I optimize this SQL CONCAT query to not have duplicate information?

Tags: sql-server, xml

### Edit 2: With edits after Backs answer

So after adding the code I get the following XML, is there any way to not get the  tag? Otherwise this is exactly what I was looking for.

```
<message>
  <header>
    <command>LOCK_ORDER</command>
  </header>
  <data>
    <orders>
      <orderNr>F0123456</orderNr>
      <company>AB</company>
    </orders>
    <orderlines>
      <line>10</line>
      <line>20</line>
      <line>30</line>
      <line>40</line>
      <line>50</line>
    </orderlines>
  </data>
</message>
```

---

### Original post

I have this SQL query where I currently pick out information which looks like this:

```
<message>
  <header>
    <command>LOCK_ORDER</command>
  </header>
  <data>
    <orderlines>
        <orderNr>FO123456</orderNr>
        <company>AB</company>
        <line>1000</line>
    </orderlines>
    <orderlines>
        <orderNr>FO123456</orderNr>
        <company>AB</company>
        <line>2000</line>
      </orderlines>
      <orderlines>
        <orderNr>FO123456</orderNr>
        <company>AB</company>
        <line>3000</line>
      </orderlines> 
  </data>
</message>
```

The SQL query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @orderNr nvarchar(40)

SET @orderNr = 'FO123456'

DECLARE @result xml = null

SET @result = (SELECT CONCAT('<message><header><command>LOCK_ORDER</command></header><data>',
            CONCAT((
                         SELECT order_num AS orderNr, line_num AS line, orderline.company 
                         FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
                         INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
                         WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y' for xml auto,elements
            )
,'</data></message>')
))

SELECT @result
```

But then I realized there will never be an instance where the information sent into this function will ever have multiple different orderNr or company so they it's redundant to send them in multiple times.

What I would like to have is an XML which looks more in the lines of this:

```
<message>
    <header>
        <command>LOCK_ORDER</command>
    </header>
    <data>
        <orderNr>FO123456</orderNr>
        <company>AB</company>
        <orderlines>
            <line>1000</line>
            <line>2000</line>
            <line>3000</line>
        </orderlines>
    </data>
</message>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('orderlines')` as indicated below:

```
DECLARE @orderNr nvarchar(40)

SET @orderNr = 'FO123456'

DECLARE @result xml = null

SET @result = (SELECT CONCAT('<message><header><command>LOCK_ORDER</command></header><data>',
            CONCAT((
                 CONCAT((SELECT TOP 1 order_num AS orderNr, orders.company 
                 FROM ORDER_LINE orders
                 INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orders.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orders.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orders.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
                 WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y' 
                 for xml path(''),elements)
                 ,
                (SELECT line_num AS line 
                FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
                INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
                WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y' 
                for xml PATH(''), ROOT('orderlines'))
                )
            )
,'</data></message>')
))

SELECT @result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @orderNr nvarchar(40)

SET @orderNr = 'FO123456'

DECLARE @result xml = null
                    SELECT @result = CONCAT('<message><header><command>LOCK_ORDER</command></header><data>',
                         (SELECT 
                           order_num         AS orderNr
                         , orderline.company AS company
                         FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
                         INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
                         WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y'
                         GROUP BY
                           order_num        
                         , orderline.company
                         for xml path('orders')
                         )
                         ,
                         (
                         SELECT line_num AS line 
                         FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
                         INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
                         WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y'

                         for xml path(''),ROOT ('orderlines')
                         ),'</data></message>'
                         )

SELECT @result
```